# A procedure imported by 'myCLIdll.dll' could not be loaded - only on Vista 32bit

Tags: c#, c++, .net, dll

I have a C++ CLI dll type project - .Net 4.5.1, that wraps a native C++ dll type project. When I call methods from the CLI dll from my C# application, it works with no problem on Windows 7 (32 and 64 bit), 8 and 8.1, but on Vista 32 bit I get:

System.IO.Exception: A procedure imported by 'myCLIdll.dll' could not be loaded.

I cannot understand why I only get this on Vista, I have spent days on this and it is very frustrating, can anyone think of a reason why this might be happening?

I have created a sample solution to try and replicate the problem, but this works fine, I have compared all the settings and they are the same, Dependency Walker does not help, I am at a lost to know what to try next!

Many thanks

Julian

Comment: Do you *really* have a 63 bit Windows 7? ;-)

Comment: @RogerRowland If he is really _positive_ about it, it might work ;)

Comment: well spotted! corrected

Comment: Do you have Vista SP2 installed? That's necessary for .NET 4.5.1

Comment: Yes, that is installed, I thought the same originally:(

Comment: System.IO.Exception is meaningless.  Document it properly, show the stack trace.  Debug by enabling loader snaps.